# Comparing Data between two excel files using foreach loop

Tags: excel, string, powershell

I am trying to check which resources(Excel1) are suitable for role(Excel2) by doing a skill match. There are multiple skills associated to both the role and resource and the data should be formatted before comparing. I have used foreach for both the files and if statement to compare the skill. Code works fine when we have few rows in the files but the input files have ~350 and ~7k rows which takes hours to run and write data to an output excel

''''

```
#Reading the demand data row by row and Formatting the skill to compare with resource skills
If($totalNoOfRecords -gt 1){
for ($i = 2; $i -le $totalNoOfRecords; $i++){
$RoleSkills = $MODWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i,$RoleSkillcolNo).text
$RoleId = $MODWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i,$RoleIDColNo).text
$ResMngtLvlFrom = $MODWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i,$RoleLvlFromColNo).text
$ResMngtLvlTo = $MODWorkSheet.Cells.Item($i,$RoleLvlToColNo).text

$roleSKill = $RoleSkills -replace 'p.? - '
$Rskill = $roleSKill -replace '[0-9] - ',''
$s, $s1,$s2,$s3,$s4,$s5 = $Rskill | foreach split '|'
If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($s1))){
$s1Search = $s1.Split("(")[0].Trim()} Else {$s1Search = ""}
If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($s2))){
$s2Search = $s2.Split("(")[0].Trim()}Else {$s2Search = ""}
If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($s3))){
$s3Search = $s3.Split("(")[0].Trim()}Else {$s3Search = ""}
If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($s4))){
$s4Search = $s4.Split("(")[0].Trim()}Else {$s4Search = ""}
If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($s5))){
$s5Search = $s5.Split("(")[0].Trim()}Else {$s5Search = ""}

If($totalNoOfResRecords -gt 1){
for ($j = 2; $j -le $totalNoOfResRecords; $j++)
{
$ResSkills = $ResWorkSheet.Cells.Item($j,$ResSkillcolumnNo).text
$ResEID = $ResWorkSheet.Cells.Item($j,$ResEIDColNo).text
$ResAvlDate = $ResWorkSheet.Cells.Item($j,$ResAvlDatecolumnNo).text
$Clearance = $ResWorkSheet.Cells.Item($j,$ResClearancecolumnNo).text
$ResCurrClient = $ResWorkSheet.Cells.Item($j,$ResCurClientcolumnNo).text
$ResourceLevel = $ResWorkSheet.Cells.Item($j,$ResLevelcolumnNo).text
If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($s1Search))){
If (($ResSkills -match $s1Search) -eq "True")
{
$SkillIndex = $ResSkills.IndexOf($s1Search)
$Skilllength = $s1Search.Length
$substring = $ResSkills.Substring($SkillIndex+$Skilllength+2)
$Index = $substring.IndexOf(")")
$SkilPro = $substring.Substring(0,$Index)
}
Else {$SkilPro = ""}
}
If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($s2Search))){
If (($ResSkills -match $s2Search) -eq "True")
{
$SkillIndex2 = $ResSkills.IndexOf($s2Search)
$Skilllength2 = $s2Search.Length
$substring2 = $ResSkills.Substring($SkillIndex2+$Skilllength2+2)
$Index2 = $substring2.IndexOf(")")
$SkilPro2 = $substring2.Substring(0,$Index2)
}
Else {$SkilPro2 = ""}
}
If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($s3Search))){
If (($ResSkills -match $s3Search) -eq "True")
{
$SkillIndex3 = $ResSkills.IndexOf($s3Search)
$Skilllength3 = $s3Search.Length
$substring3 = $ResSkills.Substring($SkillIndex3+$Skilllength3+2)
$Index3 = $substring3.IndexOf(")")
$SkilPro3 = $substring3.Substring(0,$Index3)
}
Else {$SkilPro3 = ""}
}
If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($s4Search))){
If (($ResSkills -match $s4Search) -eq "True")
{
$SkillIndex4 = $ResSkills.IndexOf($s4Search)
$Skilllength4 = $s3Search.Length
$substring4 = $ResSkills.Substring($SkillIndex4+$Skilllength4+2)
$Index4 = $substring4.IndexOf(")")
$SkilPro4 = $substring4.Substring(0,$Index4)
}
Else {$SkilPro4 = ""}
}
If (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($s5Search))){
If (($ResSkills -match $s5Search) -eq "True")
{
$SkillIndex5 = $ResSkills.IndexOf($s5Search)
$Skilllength5 = $s3Search.Length
$substring5 = $ResSkills.Substring($SkillIndex5+$Skilllength5+2)
$Index5 = $substring5.IndexOf(")")
$SkilPro5 = $substring5.Substring(0,$Index5)
}
Else {$SkilPro5 = ""}
}

If((($ResSkills -match $s1Search) -eq "True") -or (($ResSkills -match $s2Search) -eq "True") -or (($ResSkills -match $s3Search) -eq "True") -or (($ResSkills -match $s4Search) -eq "True") -or (($ResSkills -match $s5Search) -eq "True") ){
Write-Host $RoleId,$ResEID, $s1Search,$SkilPro,$s2Search,$SkilPro2,$s3Search,$SkilPro3,$s4Search,$SkilPro4,$s5Search,$SkilPro5
}
}
}
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

It's slow because it's trying to process if via Excel process. Maybe you can try to import the data as CSV and use [Join-Object](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Join-Object.ps1). You can check the blogpost - https://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/

Comment: The data are not the same on the columns to be compared and there is a possibility of finding multiple matches for 1 search.  It is something like going through the 2nd file to find one (there are multiple search strings) of the search string and write all the possible matches and then search for the next search string.

Comment: @SAG Mvasi01 is correct. Doing this using Excel COM object is way too slow. Save your Excel files as Csv and use `Import-Csv` to load the data in easy to use objects. Also,try to **indent** your code so it gets readable.